# Show sometimes only first author

Tags: citing, scrbook

assume there is a paper written by Foo and Bar.

When there is a citation, I want to show sometimes(!) only the first author (Foo) and the rest of the time all authors (foo/Bar). The reason is that I have table and the first column is for the paper citations. However, the column has fixed width, therefore sometimes i get an ugly result if there are more than two authors, see:

[image]

I am using `scrbook`.

Comment: Would you mind telling us what package (and style) you use for citing (`natbib`, `biblatex`, ...)? A [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) would be very helpful indeed. Apart from that, it is really not a good idea to use one citation and at times another - it will confuse the reader.

Comment: its true; it will be confusing. Do you have any suggestion how I can resolve this otherwise? I use bibliography=totoc and scrbook (is this what you were asking for? -- sorry I am a Latex newbie.)

Comment: That information does, unfortunately, not suffice to help you properly. Prepare a short MWE, so we can see what code you use. [How do I make LaTeX push long citations to a new line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2773/35864) and the linked questions might help you, too.

Comment: You could also make the first column wider.

Comment: That wouldn't be feasible since the text in the second column would be squeezed too much. Now I just replaced the \cite{...} with text and used \newline together with p{3cm}, so the Zitation is not clickable anymore but it fits; and it is cited somewhere also, so the bibliography is build correctly.

Comment: This is probably the best you can do in that particular situation.

Comment: Why not (in this particular case) just manually add the information in a way that allows line breaks and add just a `\nocite{<key>}` so it is included in the bibliography.  You would lose the hyperlink, but that is surely better than what you have right now (judging by the image in the question)....