# References citation does not go in a new line

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking

An image is more expressive then words...

[image: Here's the problem]

How you can see, the citation of a \bibitem does not go in a new line.
This is my code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Documentazione ffmpeg x x x x x x x x x x x x]{ffmpegdoc}
Descrizione progetto ffmpeg\\   
\url{http://ffmpeg.org/about.html}
\end{thebibliography}
```

and then

```
\cite{ffmpegdoc}
```

all that "x" is just for extremes the problem

Any idea in what's the problem?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/how-do-i-make-latex-push-long-citations-to-a-new-line/2774

Comment: YOU SAVE ME!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really simple...

use the follow package...

```
\usepackage{breakcites}
```