# Latex citations package pushes text outside margins

Tags: citing, line-breaking, margins

For my thesis I'm using a template which combines multiple packages. As shown in the example, I have two paragraphs of text where the first paragraph has text outside the text margins, while there are no problems in the second paragraph. I haven't found a solution that solves this yet.

A 'minimal example' from my text: (I hope I didn't include too much unnecessary code.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,
                openright,titlepage,fleqn,
               headinclude,parskip,footinclude,
               numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[british]{babel} 
\usepackage{scrhack} % ignore warnings about deprecated KOMA-Script

\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\usepackage[floatperchapter,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing,linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

% Custom Layout width of page
% For Final thesis use Classicthesis margins
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.bib}
@article{Day2009InformationChains,
    title = {{Information Flow Impediments in Disaster Relief Supply Chains}},
    year = {2009},
    author = {Day, Jamison and Junglas, Iris and Silva, Leiser},
}
@article{Hsu2014Risk-basedOperations,
    title = {{Risk-based spatial zone determination problem for stage-based evacuation operations}},
    year = {2014},
    author = {Hsu, Yu-Ting and Peeta, Srinivas}
}
@article{Yuan2015MultimodalArea,
    title = {{Multimodal}},
    year = {2015},
    author = {Yuan, Fang and Puchalsky, Christopher M.}
}
@article{Karbovskii2018MultimodelDynamics,
    title = {{Multimodel agent-based}},
    year = {2018},
    author = {Karbovskii, Vladislav and Voloshin, Daniil and Karsakov, Andrey and Bezgodov, Alexey and Gershenson, Carlos}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}


As mentioned, post-disaster information is dynamic in nature. \citet{Day2009InformationChains}~identify eight theoretical categories of information flow impediments, which could explain this dynamic ....

The focus of recent models for mass evacuation has been on including risk~\citep{Hsu2014Risk-basedOperations} and integrating multimodality  in mass evacuation models~\citep{Yuan2015MultimodalArea,Karbovskii2018MultimodelDynamics}. However, mass evacuation literature ....

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The resulting text this code produces is:

[image]

As can be seen from the produced PDF, the first paragraph has text outside the margins, while the second paragraph hasn't. 
My question would be: How can I make Latex put all text within the text margins.

This doesn't work for me:

I've tried to add these lines, [as suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152548), but this didn't work for me:

```
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakcites}
```

Also, of course, I can rewrite that paragraph to solve the problem, but I'm sure there should be a better way of solving this. Also because I have a very long text, where this issue turns up more often.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `~` before and after you use the `citet`/`citep` command. `~` is a non-breaking space character which is forcing 'Day, Junglas, and Silva (2009) identify' to stay on the same line. But in my opinion this is unnecessary.

See below, I've removed all instances of `~` and the text is typeset fine. There is nothing wrong with having the reference on a different line to the next/previous word. It actually makes the text spacing much improved overall.

[image]

Comment: I might add that the custom of putting `~` in front of a `\cite` makes sense in case of numeric citations where a "[2]" might look a bit lonely of shoved to the next line, but for citations with long labels as they appear in an author-year style, that might be too much.