# Citation in two column document

Tags: citing, two-column, multicolumn

I'm using the Springer template by `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}`. I'd like to use the citation by `\cite{}` with the column break. As can be seen in the figure below the citations are pushing the limits.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here%\thanks{Grants or other notes
%about the article that should go on the front page should be
%placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}
}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do please tell us which bibliography style you employ and which citation management package (if any) you load. Incidentally, the sample code you posted doesn't contain a single `\cite` instruction and hence can't be used to investigate the problem you're trying to fix.

Comment: The bibliography style used is `\bibliographystyle{spbasic}`.

Comment: Do you employ the `natbib` citation management package? (You should.)

Comment: @Mico this solve the problem, thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the formatting issue was solved in the comments. (The OP needed to load the `natbib` package.)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
\usepackage{breakcites}
```

to your preamble to make the citation markers break at the end of the lines. If this does not work, see more options [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2773/150114). Here is an example, modified from the SVJour3 template [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/svjour3-(springer-journals)):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
%\thanks{Grants or other notes
%about the article that should go on the front page should be
%placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}

%\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Too abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{Citations in left column}
\label{sec:1}
Text with citations that break lines \cite{RefB} and \cite{RefJ}.

\section{Blind text}
\blindtext[2]

\section{Citations in right column}
These citations also break properly~\cite{RefJ} and~\cite{RefB}.


% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{Author, 2017}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
\bibitem[Extremely Long Author Name, 2017]{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (2017)
% Format for books
\bibitem[Slightly Shorter Author Name, 2018]{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

[image: svjour3 document with long citations that break at the end of the line]

Comment: Loading the `breakcites` package won't solve the OP's formatting issues, as they were caused by a failure to load the `natbib` package.