# Overflow boxes caused by references

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Line breaking (or hyphenation?) of references in apalike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437/line-breaking-or-hyphenation-of-references-in-apalike)

I have downloaded styles for my BibTeX, which is called "apalike". The problem is that when I use `\cite` then references are not using `\linebreak` in a proper place and they cause reference problem. I am not sure how to ensure that the `\linebreak` will be always in the correct place

UPDATE:

It is indeed a duplicate, the answer from the other question helped in my case.

Comment: Please add a few more details or, best, a complete minimum working example (MWE). At a minimum, t would be helpful to know the documentclass, which packages you're loading, and if you use LaTeX's built-in `\cite` command or a citation command provided by a package such as `natbib`.

Comment: @Mico I have copy-pasted my main file, hope it is enough. If not, please let me know what else I should include. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very helpful. I assume you've been running pdflatex on this file, followed by a bibtex run, followed by two more pdflatex runs, correct? Two quick questions: first, you mention you're not getting the command `\breakline` to work properly -- did you mean `\linebreak`? Second, could you provde a few examples of the word, or words, that aren't being broken, i.e., hyphenated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mico I have included the screenshot with the error and the code corresponding latex code. Hope it is what you expected. The answer to your question is yes: I have compiled the way you said

Comment: What would be helpful is a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  Remove anything that is not absolutely required to reproduce the problem. For example, I don't have `immphddef.sty` -- Is that really required to reproduce this problem?  Nor do I have all your chapters, which means that you code won't compile for me.

Comment: @YuppieNetworking exactly! I searched for similar problem but I did not find it! The solution from the link helped me! Thanks!